# Automatic Wordpress Backup Plugin works, but says it's not

Tags: plugins, backup

I just installed Automatic Wordpress Backup on a fresh install of wordpress, with no other plugins installed, nothing else has changed from the default install.

The plugin is saying zip is not found, I verified with my host that it is, and updated the path for it in automatic-wordpress-backup.php.

I also have debug turned on, and am about to have to turn it off due to the number of warnings and notices displayed. It appears to be mostly Notices about deprecated arguments and Warning: Cannot modify header information.

It also causes me to just get a blank page after updating info, for example I just changed the permalinks, after I hit save it takes me to a blank page, it made & saved the changes, but I can't tell my client that it's just going to work that way.

Is this normal? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [plugin's description in repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-wordpress-backup/) says following:

> Important caveat: this plugin currently has to be run on a linux server. Also, the wp-content/uploads folder has to be server-writable or it won't be able to create the zips for backup.

...which makes me think that developer was not too interested in making plugin use proper WP APIs to work robustly across different hosting server configurations.

If this plugin alone generates enough debug output to break things I'd seriously consider looking for alternative.

Comment: good point, any automated backup solutions you've used, or that you'd recommend? I know I could look and find a list pretty easily, just curious of your experience.

Comment: @Chuck I use some plugin (wp-db-backup or soemthing like that) for database backup and SSH script that logs on to server, compresses site's folder and downloads that archive. I will get to optimizing the process some day, but it works so far so not a priority.